# Downloading macOS Catalina from sources other than preferences such as web browsers

Tags: macos, catalina, mojave

Is there any way to download macOS Catalina so that the download can be paused and then resumed even if the Mac is turned off in between or the Internet connection is disrupted?

In other words, when restarting the download, its progress remains the same as it had been left earlier.

Comment: My experience is that downloads in Safari and the Mac App Store will continue from where they left off, if interrupted. I'm not sure about between restarts, though.